# Regex exact count of characters with dash in Google Forms

Tags: regex, google-forms

I'm trying to use a validation for a google doc form, but I have no luck.
The format I'm expecting is:
ABC-ABC

I've tried with

```
([A-Z]{3}\-[A-Z]{3})
```

but without luck.

As far as I understand, the expression gives no errror on regex101.com
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you forgot to anchor it `^([A-Z]{3}\-[A-Z]{3})$` maybe?

Comment: Without luck meaning it matches when it shouldn't or vice versa? BTW, no need to escape the hyphen here.

Comment: When select the type from dropdown, make sure you select "Matches"